# MySQL - Issues Loading

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I've recently installed MariaDB via Homebrew on my mac, however, I'm having trouble starting it up, I get the error response below. I'm new to MySQL so don't know what I need to do to fix this. Any help is appreciated.

```
Marks-MacBook-Pro:~ morts$ mysql.server start
Starting MariaDB
.180701 13:00:42 mysqld_safe Logging to '/usr/local/var/mysql/Marks-MacBook- Pro.local.err'.
180701 13:00:42 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /usr/local/var/mysql
. ERROR!
```

Comment: What does the `/usr/local/var/mysql/Marks-MacBook- Pro.local.err` error file say?

Comment: Where would I find this? I search `Marks-MacBook- Pro.local.err` in finder but nothing comes up.

Comment: just run `cat '/usr/local/var/mysql/Marks-MacBook- Pro.local.err'`

Comment: Ahhhhhh, this is the error

Comment: 2018-07-01 13:00:43 0 [ERROR] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port. Got error: 48: Address already in use
2018-07-01 13:00:43 0 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ?
2018-07-01 13:00:43 0 [ERROR] Aborting

Comment: Apparently there is another mysqld running, how would I go about closing that off?

Comment: I've managed to kill it and now it works, thanks a lot for your help